# Why is Eloquent with() not doing the join?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to have a one-to-many-relationship in Laravel Eloquent. The problem is, that I cannot get a question together with its protectionclass, e.g. `Question::with(protectionclass)->get();` This returns the questions only.
I have Questions and I have a corresponding protectionclass.
One Question maps to one protectionclass and a protectionclass can have many questions.
The code is also stored in git with a db seeder: [My Git](https://git.diebold-it.de/johannes/Eloquent_with_Problem.git)
I am using Laravel 10.1.5 with Jetstream, vuejs, tailwindcss and Inertia. But the problem is within Laravel.

the two Models are:

```
class ProtectionClass extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'protectionclasses';

    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => '',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'protectionclass_id');
    }


}
```

and

```
class Question extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
            'protectionclass_id',
            'question',
            'weight',
    ];


    protected $attributes = [
        'protectionclass_id' => 1,
    ];



    public function protectionclass(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ProtectionClass::class, 'protectionclass_id');
    }
}
```

The migrations are:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('protectionclasses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('protectionclass_id');

            $table->string('question');
            $table->integer('weight')->default(1);
            $table->foreign('protectionclass_id')->references('id')->on('protectionclasses');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

this is working fine but returning the protection class only:
`Question::find(1)->protectionclass;`

Does anybody have any idea? I am struggling for hours now...
Thank you very much!

Best regards
Johannes

When I call `$questions = Question::with('protectionclass')->get();` I get back all questions but without the corresponding protectionclass.
I excpect to have it with the protectionclass.

Comment: If you do `dd($questions->first->protectionclass)`, what do you get? Also, when you say *"this is working fine but returning the protection class only: `Question::find(1)->protectionclass;`"* **that is expected**; you're only accessing `->protectionclass`, not the associated question... If you did `$question = Question::find(1);`, **then** `dd($question, $question->protectionclass)`, you should see two things being output by that (`dd()` is "dump and die", a debugging tool that dumps variables and kills execution so you can see what things are in the code)

Answer (score 0):

The `with()` method brings the information in eager load format, that is, it already preloads the relation in the object instance.

This preload is stored in the access to the relation through the model: `$question->protectionclass` which will give you access to its parent.
The reverse case of `$protectionclass->questions` will give you access to the collection of items it owns.

> I excpect to have it with the protectionclass.

You already have access to the protectionClass data, so `$question->protectionclass->name;`

If the relation physically exists in the already populated database and it is not returning anything when calling the relation, check its keys in the relation's functions in the model:

```
//Laravel doc exemples
$this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
$this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```